# Autowire Generic Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How do I autowire a generic bean? Example

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchConfig {

    final MessageSource messageSource;

    @Bean
    public <T> BeanValidatingItemProcessor<T> itemBeanValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        validator.afterPropertiesSet();

        BeanValidatingItemProcessor<T> beanValidatingItemProcessor = new BeanValidatingItemProcessor<>(validator);
        beanValidatingItemProcessor.setFilter(false);

        return beanValidatingItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step homeCareDetailStep(BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareDetailDTO> itemBeanValidator){
        //do something
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step homeCareProviderStep(BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareProviderDTO> itemBeanValidator){
        //do something
    }
}
```

I get the following errror in the IDE "Could not autowire. No beans of BeanValidatingItemProcessor type found"

Another potential solution to my problem may be the use of a service, but not sure what drawbacks I may face.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ItemBeanValidatorImpl<T> implements ItemBeanValidator<T> {

    final MessageSource messageSource;

    public <T> BeanValidatingItemProcessor<T> itemBeanValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        validator.afterPropertiesSet();

        BeanValidatingItemProcessor<T> beanValidatingItemProcessor = new BeanValidatingItemProcessor<>(validator);
        beanValidatingItemProcessor.setFilter(false);

        return beanValidatingItemProcessor;
    }

}

public interface ItemBeanValidator<T> {

    <T> BeanValidatingItemProcessor<T> itemBeanValidator();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your bean creates `BeanValidatingItemProcessor` of type `T`. what is T in this case?

You should set it to be `public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareDetailDTO> itemBeanValidator()`

Comment: The problem is I have probably 30 different beans that I need to validate and was hoping to pass in the Type to BeanValidatingItemProcessor while injecting the bean in another bean. The other problem is is the BeanValidatingItemProcessor needs the MessageSource service.

Comment: if messageSource is also a bean than it's not a problem, pass it like you pass the processor to the steps. as for the 30 different beans- don't think there's a way around it. if you need 30 types of beans, you need 30 beans

Comment: But how can I create a generic BeanValidatingItemProcessor without having to create 30 different BeanValidatingItemProcessor methods specifying they type each time. Example, public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareDetailDTO>  and public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareProviderDTO> etc

Comment: You can't. Basically a bean is an instance - how can you create 30 different generic instances without generating 30? same problem. you can maybe try to create a factory, and then have one bean for the factory that will get the class and create the instance

Comment: Take a look at my updated question and let me know if you think the generic service approach would work.

Comment: I think the same issue will happen - spring needs to generate something (for the `@Service`) but it can't, cause it can't decide what T is

Comment: Okay, any examples on the factory approach?

Comment: I posted a potential solution as an answer although I feel like a factory approach might be cleaner. I'm drawing a blank on how to create it though.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution although not pretty. Perhaps a factory approach would be cleaner.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BatchValidatorConfig {

    final MessageSource messageSource;

    @Bean
    public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareDetailDTO> homeCareDetailValidator() {
        return new ItemBeanValidator<HomeCareDetailDTO>(messageSource).validate();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareProviderDTO> homeCareProviderValidator() {
        return new ItemBeanValidator<HomeCareProviderDTO>(messageSource).validate();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareSumDTO> homeCareSumValidator() {
        return new ItemBeanValidator<HomeCareSumDTO>(messageSource).validate();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<HomeCareCorporateDTO> homeCareCorporateValidator() {
        return new ItemBeanValidator<HomeCareCorporateDTO>(messageSource).validate();
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private class ItemBeanValidator<T> {

        MessageSource messageSource;

        public BeanValidatingItemProcessor<T> validate() {
            LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
            validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
            validator.afterPropertiesSet();

            BeanValidatingItemProcessor<T> beanValidatingItemProcessor = new BeanValidatingItemProcessor<>(validator);
            beanValidatingItemProcessor.setFilter(false);
            return beanValidatingItemProcessor;
        }

    }

}
```